# Подзапрос в select

Tags: c#, linq, запрос

В базе связь один ко многим, но связь храниться в 1-м поле, просто `ID` перечислены через запятую (1,2,3).

Получился такой запрос:

```
        var query = (from _item in db.item
             where _item.date >= DateFrom && _item.dateto <= DateTo
             join _box in db.box on _item.boxid equals _box.boxid
             select new ReportStatementPeriodAgreement()
             {
                ItemName = _item.itemnum,
                Box = _box.boxname,
                Type = (from _type in db.type where _type.Split(',').Contains(_item.typeid.ToString())).ToList()
             })
             .ToList();
```

В Type по сути может быть либо склееная строка или список строк, мне без разницы.
Но вот беда `Split` нельзя использовать внутри linq. Как быть ?

Comment: мне кажется, или вы забыли `select` указать для подзапроса? У меня именно на это ругается а `Split` вроде как и ни причем, в `where` попадает результат `Contains`, а он `bool` что и требуется

Comment: @rdorn да, там и правда `select` не хватает. Но это не отменяет того факта, что провайдеры `linq` не умеют транслировать вызов `Split`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нормальный вариант только один - никогда так не делать.

Что linq2sql, что EF, что NHibernate - все предоставляют нормальные способы реализации отношений "многие-ко-многим через промежуточную таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Из ненормальных же вариантов могу предложить такой:

```
var query = (from _item in db.item
             where _item.date >= DateFrom && _item.dateto <= DateTo
             join _box in db.box on _item.boxid equals _box.boxid
             select new ReportStatementPeriodAgreement()
             {
                ItemName = _item.itemnum,
                Box = _box.boxname,
                Type = (
                  from _type in db.type 
                  where ("," + _type.typeids + ",").Contains("," + _item.typeid + ",")
                  select type).ToList()
             })
             .ToList();
```

Но тут сразу предупреждаю: сервер СУБД не сумеет оптимизировать подобный запрос.